# part of my python code not running/executing

Tags: python

```
 def win_check(board,mark):


        return ((board[7] == mark and board[8] == mark and board[9] == mark) or # across the top
        (board[4] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[6] == mark) or # across the middley

        (board[1] == mark and board[2] == mark and board[3] == mark) or # across the bottom
        (board[7] == mark and board[4] == mark and board[1] == mark) or # down the middle
        (board[8] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[2] == mark) or # down the middle
        (board[9] == mark and board[6] == mark and board[3] == mark) or # down the right side
        (board[7] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[3] == mark) or # diagonal
        (board[9] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[1] == mark)) # diagonal








     print('Welcome To Tic Tac Toe')

        while True:

            the_board =[' ']*10
            player1_symbol, player2_symbol = player_symbol()
            player_turn = play_first()
            print(player_turn + 'Will go first')
            Ready_to_play = input('Ready to play?, Yes or No')
            print('ready to play running')
            if Ready_to_play == 'Yes' or Ready_to_play == 'yes':
                print('game on')
                game_on = True
                print('game on runs')
            else:
                game_on = False


            while game_on :

                if player_turn == 'Player 1':

                    print('am running player 1')

                    show_board(the_board)
                    print('am showing the board')
                    position = player_choice(the_board)

                    place_symbol(the_board, player1_symbol,position)
                    print('i added the marker')
                    show_board(the_board)
                    if win_check(the_board, player1_symbol): #this code is not executing 

                        show_board(the_board)
                        print('check if there is a win')
                        print('Player 1 wins!!')
                        game_on = False
                    else:
                        if full_board_check(the_board): # this one also

                            show_board(the_board)
                            print('Tie game!!')
                            game_on = False
                        else:
                            player_turn = 'Player 2'

            else:

                print('am running player 2')
                show_board(the_board)
                print('showing the board')
                position = player_choice(the_board)
                place_symbol(the_board, player2_symbol,position)
                print('adding the marker')
                show_board(the_board)
                if win_check(the_board, player2_symbol):  # this code too not executing 


                    show_board(the_board)
                    print('Player 2 wins!!')
                    game_on = False
                else:



                    if full_board_check(the_board):



                        show_board(the_board)
                        print('Tie game!!')
                        game_on = False

                    else:


                        player_turn = 'Player 1 '


            if not replay():
                print('End of game')  

                break
```

am using the jupyter notebook for the code, when i run each code block they

all run well without any problem but running the program as a whole the

win_check function does not run, the code was to check if the a player has won or if the board is full so that the program can reset, but as it stands now it just jump to the replay function.. any help

on what i should do

Comment: Please take a close look at the code in your question and take the time to format it correctly. As it stands, all your code would be part of the `win_check` function, which has a `return` at the first line. Also your indentation levels vary between lines and you have multiple unneccessary blank lines, leading to unneccessary scrolling.

Comment: How do you know the function doesn't run? Try putting `print("in win_check")` in the function.

Comment: @Barmar yeah it is not running

Comment: But everything else runs? It keeps asking you for a choice, printing the board, etc.? There's no way it will skip over the function call. You did put that print statement *before* the `return` statement, right?

Comment: yes i did put the print statement before the return statement